# How can I change the file size of photos uploaded to Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I have uploaded my photos in Google Photos with upload size Original. Now only 4.4GB is left out of 15GB. I have deleted photos on my phone after uploading them to Google Photos.

Now I changed my Google Photos settings, I have selected Upload size to High Quality. But still, it is showing 4.4GB left.

I want to keep all my photos in Google Photos as well as I want to get more free space which is occupied by the photos with Original size.

Comment: Anyone know how to change quality of specific photos/videos rather than compressing everything?

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to https://photos.google.com.
2. Select Options from the top left of this page, then select Settings near the bottom of the Options menu.
3. Change the radio button to High Quality (free unlimited storage).
4. Just under this, you will see two options: "Buy Storage" & "Recover Storage".
5. Select Recover Storage and you will be presented with the option to "Compress".
6. Select Compress and it will warn it could take up to an hour to complete.
7. Go ahead and you will have then compressed all your original-sized photos to High Quality and recover the space.
8. If you don't have the full-size photo's backed up, be aware this option is not reversible.

Comment: This is correct, and still true, verified today.

Answer (score 1):

You already uploaded them as Original size, so changing to High Quality after the fact it'll still report 4.4 GB free.  You'd have to make sure the photos were still on your phone, remove them from Google Photos, then re-upload them with the High Quality setting.

Changing to High Quality after an upload won't affect photos already uploaded in Original quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the Google Photos web app settings page.

1. Go to http://photos.google.com from your browser.
2. Click on the settings button ([image]).
3. Click the Recover Storage button.

[image]

That it :)

Answer (score 0):

The size is counted for the photos that are being uploaded from the date the Google announced the storage limitation. Any photo or video that were uploaded in any quality in the past do not count against the storage quota. Thats the reason you dont see reduction in the available limit. The size difference matters after the announcement only.